# Is there a way to strip whitespace around a template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template for a plaintext email:

```
Here's some info.

{% if variable %}
Additional info.
{% else %}
Alternative info.
{% endif %}

{% if another_variable %}
IMPORTANT MESSAGE
{% endif %}

Final thoughts.
```

Unfortunately, since this is a plaintext template, rather than HTML, the newline characters that appear after each template tag are being included in the output. So if `variable == True` and `another_variable == False`, the output looks like this:

```
Here's some info.


Additional info.



Final thoughts.
```

There are a ton of extra empty lines between everything, which I would like for there to be just one.

Is there any way around this problem without mushing all the tags together (which makes the template difficult to read)?

Comment: Not very helpful here, but adding a bit since it is a long and ongoing issue. To start reading up there is [this google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/jWtqOq6C7gM). Then there is [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2594#comment:56) and especially aaugustin's comment is significant. With 1.8, official support for alternative template engines (even multiple in a single project) is available, so if your project is already in 1.8 then Jinja2 for the email template might be the best option. If not, then it has to be workarounded. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\n+')
regex.sub('\n', template)
```

This will replace consecutive newlines with single one.

Comment: Huh, I hadn't considered post-processing as a potential solution to this. I'll give that a shot!

Comment: Post-processing with regex worked a treat! Thanks so much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can custom your one. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/) for some guidance.

Comment: I don't need custom template tags. I need a way to prevent the lines that have built-in tags on them from printing newlines into my plaintext output.

Comment: I tried you code in my project, but I got the output all in one line, did i miss thing? Or did you?